# How to force the width of the content of an element (and not the element itself)?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have two squares with a number in each, centered. The number may be one or two digits, and I would like the centering to be done on the basis of two digits, even for the case where there is just one (this is going to be a clock for my home dashboard, sometimes the hour will be `8` and sometimes `14`).

The code below shows a draft of the final effect, both numbers are centered but I do not know how to force `1` to be of the width of two digits. I am not aiming for perfection (digits are generally of different widths), but rather to say something along the lines of `<span class="el" width_of_text_for_this_element="2em;">1</span>` (this is of course pseudo-code)

```css
.clock {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
}

.el {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <span class="el">1</span>
  <span class="el">18</span>
</div>
```

I believe that what I am looking for is a way to apply a style to the content of an element (and not the element itself), but I am not sure.

Comment: What is your browser requirements?

Comment: Could you post a photo of what you want to achieve in centering on the basis of two digits?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: ideally Chrome, latest version -- this is for my home dashboard so I can choose whatever works (the browser just needs to support kiosk mode)

Comment: @Eytan: If you run Temani's answer this is exactly the effect I am looking for

Comment: @WoJ you can consider accepting or upvoting the answer then :) or leave me a comment if there is something missing ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I am not only considering but I am accepting with pleasure and gratitude :) (I am usually waiting a few days to avoid switching solutions). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below using `ch` unit

```css
.clock {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}

.el {
  font-size: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width:2ch;
  height:2ch;
  text-align:right; /* Or left based on your needs */
  border:30px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <span class="el">1</span>
  <span class="el">18</span>
</div>
```